# Understanding Java API's

Tags: api, java-8, programming-languages, java

I wanted to ask little bit generic question about Java API's. I'm new in Java, learning myself and of course I enjoy it while learning. But when it comes to Java API's, to me it's hard to understand even if I know OOP's Concepts. Actually I often confuse while reading JavaDoc's. Agree that there are  bunch of information about what class's(interface, enum..) has, what they extend, implements or whatever. Even though I couldn't use them without looking from the internet.

So, what is the best way of learning those API's in general, just give me your followed way while learning Java.

Comment: That's primarily opinion based and thus I'd say out of scope for SO. The most general way to learn a new API is probably using it (e.g. trying examples) and reading documentation/tutorials when you don't understand how/why something works - in one word: experience.

Comment: Nothing beats practice. Try out examples, and use your debugger which your program doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: Install IDEA, and do different projects. In 3-6 month you can go find a Junior job - depends on talent and passion.

Comment: @Divers, yeah  you are right, in every little pice of code I use debugger. As you know in here also  we couldn't see exactly what is going on inside of API's.

Comment: No, we can - just attach sources.

Comment: I’d start with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ .

Answer (score 2):

The best way to learn Java is to read articles with examples. It is common approach for newbies and professionals. JavaDocs is dry, too formal and really are often confusing (especially for methods from Stream API with 3+ generic parameters).

Answer (score 2):

The way I did was to read certification books, for OCA and OCP, they start from the very basic, and builds up on the top of that, with examples and exercises.

It is a really nice way to build your core knowledge of the language. With that solidified knowledge you can start reading articles about different subjects in the Java universe ...

Just be patient, code as much as possible, and it will become natural aftar some time.

Comment: thank you for your answer yeah, I consider to read those kind of certification books